# Ionic populating a list with a time delay

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

Let's say I have a list in a page called `ListPage` in ionic

```
<ion-list #list>
</ion-list>
```

And I have a custom component named `ListItem` with the following code:

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-avatar item-start>
        <img src="{{avatar}}"
    </ion-avatar>
    <h2>{{Name}}</h2>
</ion-item>
```

How would I keep adding new `ListItem` components from a function in `ListPage.ts` if the function
runs in a timer and updates with new `ListPage` data every few seconds?

Thanks, much appreicated

Comment: how about using input bindings and then <list-item *ngFor="let item of listItems" [item]="item"></list-item>

Comment: Angular's animation module comes with a stagger function. This may be what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you, didn't realize *ngFor worked that way too. This solves my problem!